# Android unit testing using Mockito : can't get the right behaviour for mocks

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, android-testing

I am testing my Repository class using Mockito, specifically getProducts() functionality:

```
class Repository private constructor(private val retrofitService: ApiService) {

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: Repository? = null

        fun getInstance(retrofitService: ApiService): Repository {
            synchronized(this) {
                var instance = INSTANCE
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = Repository(retrofitService)
                }
                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }
        }
    }

    suspend fun getProducts(): ProductsResponse = withContext(IO) {
        retrofitService.getProducts()
    }
}
```

This is my test class:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class RepositoryTest {

    // Class under test
    private lateinit var repository: Repository

    // Executes each task synchronously using Architecture Components.
    @get:Rule
    val instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    // Set the main coroutines dispatcher for unit testing.
    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @get:Rule
    var mainCoroutineRule = MainCoroutineRule()

    @Mock
    private lateinit var retrofitService: ApiService

    @Before
    fun createRepository() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        repository = Repository.getInstance(retrofitService)
    }

    @Test
    fun test() = runBlocking {

        // GIVEN
        Mockito.`when`(retrofitService.getProducts()).thenReturn(fakeProductsResponse)

        // WHEN
        val productResponse: ProductsResponse = repository.getProducts()

        println("HERE = ${retrofitService.getProducts()}")

        // THEN
        println("HERE: $productResponse")
        MatcherAssert.assertThat(productResponse, `is`(fakeProductsResponse))
    }
}
```

And my ApiService:

```
interface ApiService {
    @GET("https://www...")
    suspend fun getProducts(): ProductsResponse
}
```

When I call `repository.getProducts()`, it returns null despite the fact, that I explicitly set `retrofitService.getProducts()` to return `fakeProductsResponse`, which is being called inside repository's `getProducts()` method. It should return `fakeProductsResponse`, but it returns null.

Am I doing wrong mocking or what the problem can be? Thanks...

EDIT: this is my `MainCoroutineRule`, if you need it

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class MainCoroutineRule(val dispatcher: TestCoroutineDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()):
    TestWatcher(),
    TestCoroutineScope by TestCoroutineScope(dispatcher) {
    override fun starting(description: Description?) {
        super.starting(description)
        Dispatchers.setMain(dispatcher)
    }

    override fun finished(description: Description?) {
        super.finished(description)
        cleanupTestCoroutines()
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it because you run it in withContext(IO). The best solution is to create new unconfined dispatchers. but another solution is add Thread.sleep(3000) in your test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be a complete solution to your problem, but what I see is that your `MainCoroutineRule` overrides the mainDispatcher `Dispatchers.setMain(dispatcher)`.

But in

```
suspend fun getProducts(): ProductsResponse = withContext(IO)
```

you are explicitely setting an IO Dispatcher.

I recommend always setting the dispatcher from a property you pass via constructor:

```
class Repository private constructor(
  private val retrofitService: ApiService,
  private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher) {

    companion object {
       
        fun getInstance(retrofitService: ApiService,
                        dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO): Repository {
            // ommit code for simplicity

            instance = Repository(retrofitService, dispatcher)
            // ...
            }
        }
    }

    suspend fun getProducts(): ProductsResponse = withContext(dispatcher) {
        retrofitService.getProducts()
    }
}
```

Having it a default parameter you do not need to pass it in your regular code, but you can exchange it within your unit test:

```
class RepositoryTest {

    private lateinit var repository: Repository

    @get:Rule
    var mainCoroutineRule = MainCoroutineRule()

    @Mock
    private lateinit var retrofitService: ApiService

    @Before
    fun createRepository() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        repository = Repository.getInstance(retrofitService, mainCoroutineRule.dispatcher)
    }
}
```

For my own unit tests I am using the blocking function of `TestCoroutineDispatcher` from the `CoroutineRule` like:

```
@Test
fun aTest() = mainCoroutineRule.dispatcher.runBlockingTest {
    val acutal = classUnderTest.callToSuspendFunction()

    // do assertions
}
```

I hope this will help you a bit.

Comment: You are right about Dispatchers, this was a mistake I wasn't able to find. However, this only partially solved the problem, as it looks like there is still something missing, perhaps, Mockito stuff. Thank you anyway, it was priceless!